# Find additions only of a file from a specific version up to current HEAD

Tags: git, version-control, grep, repository, git-log

I have a git main branch.
Assume we have a main line and at various points I branch off.
So let's take a file for example:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G -> E -> J -> K -> L -> M  
  v.1.0.0         v.2.0.0       v.3.0.0                HEAD/master
```

So we have e.g. file `foo.xml` and this is its timeline and the version B of the file has the branch (v.1.0.0) and we have other changes in that branch (omitted for clarity of the diagram), then we have v2.0.0 and finally the  current status of the head/master is in the latest version of the file `M`

This file acts like a "scatch-pad" file meaning that some of the contents are added after we branch and as we move from element to element some are removed.

Question:
How can I find which elements (all actually that) were added from version J up till and including version M (I don't care if something added in J is removed in a later version, but I care to know everything that has been added in all versions)?
I would not know exactly the SHA1 of J but I would know the current HEAD and the previous branch name.
How can I do that using the git utilities?

**Note:**
I **only** care about `foo.xml` and its changes over the commits. I don't care about other files/changes

Comment: What is for you an "elements" ? A diff inside your file `foo.xml' or files added ?

Comment: @Orel:A diff inside `foo.xml` only. I only care about this file

Answer (score 0):

A simple diff seems enought

```
git diff branch-old..HEAD foo.xml |grep '^+'
```

Comment: But this will give me things **removed** along the timeline as well. I want **only** the additions per version of the file along the timeline

Comment: I have updated the command, simply add a grep to filter on new line. Warning, If a line is updated it will appear as a new one.